# Disabling swipe on a specific div

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

Having this jQuery Mobile 1.9.1 code, to take care of showing side panels when the user swipes right or left...

```
$(document).on("pageinit",".ui-page",function(){

    var $page=$(this);
    $page.on("swipeleft swiperight",function(e){
        if($page.jqmData("panel")!=="open"){
            if(e.type==="swiperight"){
                $page.find("#menu").panel("open");
            }else if(e.type==="swipeleft"){
                $page.find("#menu2").panel("open");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This creates a problem when using an image slider with swiping capabilities. Inside the slider div when I swipe right it changes to the next photo and opens the panel...

I just tryed doing this:

```
    $('#full-width-slider').swipe(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

but it doesn't work at all.

Is there any way to disable the jQuery Mobile native slide function inside the div #full-width-slider ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know of any support for a `.swipe()` method, as outlind above in your own code, `.on('swipeleft swiperight')` captures those events....so changing your `.swipe(function(e){` to `.on('swipeleft swiperight', function(e){` should give you what you want.

Comment: The $('#full-width-slider').swipe(function(e){ got it from a jquery forum. This is my first project in jquery mobile and I'm still very fresh at it :) I'm trying right now what you say!

Comment: worked fine @Ohgodwhy. Please submit it as an answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.on('swipeleft swiperight', function(e){
```

as opposed to

```
.swipe(function(e){
```

While I'm not 100% confident in this answer, a feel trials revealed that there will still be issues with the code and you might have to do a sanity check in the original element, something like,

```
if($.inArray('full-width-slider', $.trim($(e.target).prop('id')).split(' ')) > -1){
    //full with slider is the target, so return out 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this:

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

This should stop the swipe from bubbling.

Your code

```
$('#full-width-slider').swipe(function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why? There's no other swipe handler bound to that element, and `stopImmediatePropagation` simply stops propagation to other events bound on the same element. If it's bound to the document, then this will have no effect, as the propagation will still continue up the tree to the document and bubble the event.